# How to fix "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to"

Tags: android

I have a problem with transfering data from retrofit to room. I downloaded data from the API but when i try getting data in room database I receive the error :

> " Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot
>   be cast to".

Debug shows me on error in

```
 newsDao.insert((News) news);
```

AND

```
.subscribe(new Consumer<List<News>>()
```

Here is my code.

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.List;
import burtsev.a.k.news.Model.News;
import burtsev.a.k.news.Retrofit.NewsAPI;
import burtsev.a.k.news.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import burtsev.a.k.news.Room.NewsDao;
import burtsev.a.k.news.Room.NewsDatabase;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Splash instance;
    public NewsDatabase newsDatabase;

    NewsAPI newsAPI;
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    NewsDao newsDao;

    public static Splash getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        newsDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                NewsDatabase.class, "database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        newsDao = newsDatabase.newsDao();
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
        newsAPI = retrofit.create(NewsAPI.class);
        fetchData();

    }

    private void fetchData() {
        compositeDisposable.add(newsAPI.getNews().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<News>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<News> news) throws Exception {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, NewsListFragment.class);
                        // intent.putExtra("news", (Serializable) news);
                        newsDao.insert((News) news);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                }));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        compositeDisposable.clear();
        super.onStop();
    }

    public NewsDatabase getNewsDatabase() {
        return newsDatabase;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post the minimal amount of code to replicate the problem, this is a ton of code to read through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to insert list but, you are trying to cast it to an object.

so `news` is not a `News` model. it is a `List<News>`. If you want to insert all your news objects. you can try `foreach` or you can create a new function inside your `DAO` which will insert all list at once.

`foreach`;

```
for(News anews: news){
    newsDao.insert(anews);
}
```

to insert at once. new function inside your DAO class should be;

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) 
void insertAllNews(List<News> news);
```

in your `subscibe` you need to use;

```
newsDao.insertAllNews(news);
```